# Flutter SqfliteDatabaseException when updating

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

got a bit of an issue with my sqflite database, whenever I attempt to update an existing record im greeted with the following error:

[image: code execution error]

I've tried multiple irritations of the same code but here's my current setup:
here's the execution code

```
var updateDBTask = TaskModel(
                    taskType: 'task',
                    taskCompleted: 'false',
                    datetime: '${DateTime.now()}',
                    taskPriority:
                        (_newTaskPriority == 0 || _newTaskPriority == null)
                            ? '${widget.previousTaskPriority}'
                            : _newTaskPriority.toString(),
                    datetimedue: '${DateTime.now()}',
                    taskDescription: ('${_newTaskNotes.text}' == '' ||
                            '${_newTaskNotes.text}' == null)
                        ? '${widget.previousTaskDescription}'
                        : '${_newTaskNotes.text}',
                    taskTitle: ('${_newTaskTitle.text}' == '' ||
                            '${_newTaskTitle.text}' == null)
                        ? '${widget.previousTaskTitle}'
                        : '${_newTaskTitle.text}',
                    taskTag: 'defaultTagPOGGEERSWTFJIASJFOIAWJIOj');
                TasksDatabase.db_.updateTask(updateDBTask);
```

here's the code that actually updates the db:

```
updateTask(updateTask) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.rawUpdate("UPDATE " +
        TASK_TABLE_NAME +
        " SET ("
            //"id = ${updateTask.datetime}, "
            "tasktype = ${updateTask.taskType}, "
            "tasktitle = ${updateTask.taskTitle}, "
            "taskdescription = ${updateTask.taskDescription}, "
            "taskcompleted = ${updateTask.taskCompleted}, "
            "datetime = ${updateTask.datetime}, "
            "datetimedue = ${updateTask.datetimedue}, "
            "tasktag = ${updateTask.taskTag}, "
            "taskpriority = ${updateTask.taskPriority})");
    return result;
  }
```

been stuck on this for the last couple of days any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess task description is going null to the SQL string i see taskDescription = , i don't see why though, sorry.

Comment: tried fixing that incase it was a null, don't think that's the issue.

Comment: did you try placing a hardcoded string on it to see if works?

Comment: tried doing that, the issue appears when trying the update the actual db

Comment: I think the problem is related with the strings withtou '' on the sql, dbs ofter doesn't accept it, for example tasktitle=hhiuhiuh, should be tasktitle='hhiuhiuh', try check this for the strings and dates fields. Or instead of using rawquery use query with the args params i think is better.

Comment: first option didn't particularly work; would you mind elaborating on the second option

Comment: i'm sorry but i am not seeing the problem, i could maybe try help if remotely with some app to see the code in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL `UPDATE` query is invalid, no need for brackets after `SET`, string are not enclosed by quotes (and event worst have spaces in them, like in datetime). You should google around for the proper SQL syntax (example here: https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-query-insert-update.html#2) or use `update` instead of `rawUpdate`.

Also you should not put your value in the SQL query as explained here https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/sql.md#parameters

```
// Don't do
await db.rawUpdate('UPDATE MyTable SET Column1 = $val1, Column2 = $val2');

// Instead do:
await db.rawUpdate(
    'UPDATE MyTable SET Column1 = ?, Column2 = ?', [val1, val2]);
```

(As a side note you are also missing a `WHERE` clause to only update the value for a given record, here it updates the values for all records in the table)

SQL is a language!

Comment: tried doing that, I've ended up with
```Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=1 "near "VALUES": syntax error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=near "VALUES": syntax error}) sql 'UPDATE tasks SET (id, tasktype, tasktitle, taskdescription, taskcompleted, datetime, datetimedue, tasktag, taskpriority) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [2021-05-01 16:42:49.548981, task, , , false, 2021-05-01 16:42:49.548981, 2021-05-01 16:42:49.549727, defaultTagPOGGEERSWTFJIASJFOIAWJIOj, 1]})```